# Филология и лингвистика

Tags: значение-слов

То ли я раньше не замечала, то ли недавно появилась на нашей страничке надпись: форум филологов и лингвистов. Мне это сочетание кажется неверным. Лингвистика - составная часть филологии.  Все равно как сказать "форум живописцев и пейзажистов". А вы как считаете?

Р.S. Надпись не на самой страничке, а в названии вкладки в браузере.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Полностью с Вами согласен: филологи делятся на лингвистов и литературоведов.

Answer (score 4):

Тут видимо сказалась разница в терминологии отечественной и западной науки. У нас действительно принято выделять лингвистику как часть филологии. Однако на Западе лингвистику относят к семиотике (науке о знаках), а под филологией же, если верить английской [Википедии](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philology), обычно понимают исследование литературных текстов и письменных свидетельств, установление их подлинности и изначальной формы, определения смысла текста.

Западный подход к лингвистике породил в частности такой раздел науки, как [компьютерная лингвистика](http://www.krugosvet.ru/enc/gumanitarnye_nauki/lingvistika/KOMPYUTERNAYA_LINGVISTIKA.html), который отнести к филологии можно лишь с большой долей условности.

Что касается лично меня, то филологом бы я назвал человека, изучающего тексты с помощью языков, а лингвистом человека, изучающего языки с помощью текстов. Разница в приоритетах. Что-то вроде различия между историей и политологией.