# Что такое филология на самом деле?

Tags: значение-слов, терминология, значение, термины

В [вопросе](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/18855/%D0%A4%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B8-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0) человек спрашивает:

> То ли я раньше не замечала, то ли недавно появилась на нашей страничке
> надпись: форум филологов и лингвистов. Мне это сочетание кажется
> неверным. Лингвистика - составная часть филологии. Все равно как
> сказать «форум живописцев и пейзажистов». А выкак считаете?

На что получает ответ, за который проголосовало 4 человека, и который принят:

> Полностью с Вами согласен: филологи делятся на лингвистов и
> литературоведов.

В обыденном общении, когда встречаешься со словом филология оно употребляется именно в таком значение, совокупности языкознания с литературоведением.

И под филологом понимают специалиста в этих областях. Например, когда не знают, как написать что-то, говорят: «Надо спросить у филолога», т. е. у специалиста в языке.

Если возникает желание поступить в ВУЗ и получить специальность преподавателя русского, английского или другого языка, или хочешь быть переводчиком, то в ВУЗах эти специальности преподают на факультетах филологии, и студентов и выпускников считают филологами.

Например, если зайти на сайт МГУ в раздел [Филологического факультета](https://www.philol.msu.ru/studies/specializations/):

> На факультете реализуются разные образовательные программы бакалавриата
> и магистратуры в рамках двух направлений подготовки: «Филология» и
> «Фундаментальная и прикладная лингвистика». ...на направлении
> «Филология» студенты...
> обучаются… «Русский язык и литература», «Русский язык как
> иностранный», … «Теория и практика перевода» (основной язык
> английский)…

Так ми образом в словосочетании филологический факультет или факультет филологии под филологией понимается изучение языка и литературы. Он как бы объединят в себе языковые специальности.

Такая ситуация не только в этом ВУЗе и не только в России.

Однако если почитать определение филологии, приходишь в полное замешательство:

[Википедия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F):

> Филоло́гия (от др.-греч. φιλολογία, «любовь к слову») — совокупность
> наук (языкознания, текстологии, литературоведения, источниковедения,
> палеографии и др.), изучающих **культуру народа, выраженную в языке и
> литературном творчестве**.

[Большой толковый словарь](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F&all=x):

> ФИЛОЛОГИЯ, -и; ж. [от греч. philéō - люблю и lógos - учение]
> Совокупность гуманитарных наук, изучающих письменные тексты и на
> основе их языкового, содержательного и стилистического анализа -
> **историю и сущность духовной культуры данного общества**. Античная ф.
> Романская ф. Славянская ф. Филологический, -ая, -ое. Ф. факультет.
> Ф-ие науки. Ф-ие исследования. Получить ф-ое образование.

Из определения получается, что цель филологии вовсе не в изучении языка и литературы, а в изучении культуры народа, истории и сущности духовной культуры данного общества.

Но это больше похоже на культурологию.

Почему есть разница между определением филологии, и тем в каком значении её используют в общении и в названии факультетов и специальностей?

Какое правильное определение филологии?

Дайте чёткое определение филологии, которое подходит в случе факультета филологии и точное научное определение филологии, если эти определения отличаются. Если они не отличаются, дайте одно общее определение, которое подходит в обоих случаях.

Answer (score 1):

Филология отличается от лингвистики тем, что изучает культурно значимые тексты. Корпус СМС носителей таджикского языка интересовать филологов не будет, а вот романы Достоевского -- самое то.

Лингвистика -- отдельная наука, многие лингвисты обижаются, когда их называют филологами. Так что, вкратце, у филологов есть свое "языкознание", нужное для работы с текстами, их интересующими. Лингвисты же занимаются языком и тем, что ему сопутствует (вся жизнь?), в любых проявлениях.

Культурология -- это не про язык и не про тексты, а про всё понемножку, без формальных моделей и ухода в естественные науки, как в некоторых разделах лингвистики.

Comment: Я не всё понял. «Корпус СМС носителей таджикского языка» — вы имеете в виду, тексты SMS (Short Message Service — служба коротких сообщений), т. е. сообщений передаваемых с помощью сотового телефона носителями таджикского языка? «без формальных моделей» — это как?

Comment: Вы ответили вроде бы логично. Но смотрите, заходим на сайт МГУ в раздел [Филологического факультета](https://www.philol.msu.ru/studies/specializations/). Читаем: « ...по направлениям подготовки «Филология» и «Фундаментальная и прикладная лингвистика». На факультете филологии обучают прикладной лингвистике? Далее: «...на направлении „Филология“ студенты... обучаются… „Русский язык и литература“, „Русский язык как иностранный“, … „Теория и практика перевода“ (основной язык английский)…» Это как понимать? (часть 1/2).

Comment: Такая ситуация не только в этом ВУЗе и не только в России. Если ты хочешь быть переводчиком, если ты хочешь преподавать русский (английский, немецкий) язык в школе, ВУЗе или на курсах, если ты хочешь обучать русскому языку иностранцев, ты поступаешь на филологический факультет, и в названии специальности фигурирует филология. Но ведь филология, как вы пишете, занимается тем, что «изучает культурно значимые тексты», а в словаре и в Википедии вообще написано, что изучает культуру народа. Ведь между определением филологии, и тем, что относят к филологии в ВУЗах, есть явное противоречие. (2/2)

Comment: @Eagle 1) корпус таджикских СМС -- да. 2) Ну так -- например, для описания синтаксиса есть разные формальные модели типа грамматики зависимостей, генеративной грамматики и др. Ни о чем подобном для культурологии или филологии я не слышал. 3) То, что ОТиПЛ находится на филфаке МГУ, -- бюрократические и исторические издержки. Это всегда было и есть вольное отделение со своей атмосферой, кардинально отличающейся от остального филфака; и со своим -- одним из лучших в мире -- образованием. 4) Непонятно, почему вы так привязались к формальностям. Почитайте про Школу лингвистики НИУ ВШЭ, например.

Comment: Я ваш ответ оценил, но мне все равно до конца непонятно. Знаменательные слова языка обозначают понятия. Это один из фундаментальных принципов языка. Причем слова и понятия чётко связаны. Слово «яблоки» означает понятие «яблоки». Если я буду думать, что яблоки это спички, то когда вы попросите купить меня яблоки, я куплю вам спички. Вас это утроит? Думаю нет. Но я вам скажу, что это формальности, что вы прицепились, я вольный человек, учился на вольном отделении филологии, я понимаю так, яблоки как спички. Но в таком случае общение вообще потеряет смысл, как и сам язык. (1/2)

Comment: Получается что специалисты по языку, которые казалось бы должны блюсти чистоту языка, ведь язык это их призвание, в словаре дают одно определение филологии, где цель изучение культуры, а сами его использует в другом, как языкознание + литературоведение. Причём делают это в ВУЗе, так сказать, храме науки. В итоге, когда человек говорит, что он филолог, вообще не понятно, в чём он специалист. А как быть при приёме на работу. Это всё ровно, что нанять сантехника, который думает, что он плотник. Это выглядит, как шизофрения. (2/2)

Comment: @Eagle 1) Яблоки 'спички' -- выдумка, возникшая только в ваших представлениях. Это не то же самое, что лингвистика 'не филология', ведь такая лингвистика -- то, чему учат сотни студентов каждый год в России и о чем знают сотни тысяч людей по всему миру. Это устойчивое понятие, но есть еще другие вещи, которые называют лингвистикой, создавая путаницу. Например, перевод, преподавания языков, логопедия... В среде профессиональных теоретических лингвистов, однако, это не принято; для них лингвистика -- это теоретическое изучение языка, а также некоторые прикладные языковые вещи.

Comment: "1) Яблоки 'спички' -- выдумка, возникшая только в ваших представлениях". Я вам просто для примера это написал. Примеры предложений в учебнике русского языка тоже придуманы, это не реальность. И Расколькольникова тоже не существовало, и он никого не убивал.

Comment: @Eagle 2) Есть отдельная специальность – теоретическая и прикладная лингвистика. Это не филология, не литературоведение, не перевод и не преподавание иностранных языков. Когда человек говорит, что он филолог, то действительно непонятно, кто он по жизни. Может, учитель литературы, а может переводчик с иврита. Когда человек говорит, что он теоретический лингвист (обычно первое слово добавляют скорее в шутку), то сразу понятно, откуда он, с каким бэкграундом и чем занимается. (Ну, могут быть исключения, конечно...)

Comment: @Eagle наконец, не думайте, что в кратких статьях толкового словаря многолетней давности будет написано что-то исчерпывающее про филологию или что-либо еще. Вот здесь академик Плунгян довольно подробно рассказывает, что такое лингвистика (в сравнении с филологией), можете послушать! https://youtu.be/bdNScFjyAOk

Comment: На словарь пенять не надо, я привёл определение не только от туда и из Википедии, или она тоже многолетней давности? На сайте Грамота в словаре 2014 года редакции такое же определение. В Российской энциклопедии аналогичное. А даже если словарь не новый, не значит что за это время, математика, физика или химия уже изучают принципиально другие вещи. Факультетов названия тоже не новые, а значит уже тогда это противоречие существовало.

Comment: Вы ушли в сторону лингвистики, это меня пока не интересует. Я отредактировал свой вопрос и хочу получить чёткое определение филологии, которое подходит в случе факультета филологии и точное научное определение филологии, если эти определения отличаются. Если не отличаются: одно правильное определение, которое подходит в обоих случаях.

Comment: @Eagle то, что вы хотите получить, получить невозможно, так же как получить "точное" определение философии, например.

Comment: Что такое философия для меня понятно. Слово философия переводится как любовь к мудрости, и несмотря на то, что от философии откололись точные науки, свою суть она сохранила. Каждое слово имеет точное значение, иначе мы бы не могли понимать друг друга или плохо понимали. Ведь когда одни люди говорят «факультет филологии», другие понимают, что имеется ввиду и что там изучается, значит у филологии есть такое значение. Может его нет в словаре, а оно есть только в головах, но оно есть, иначе не было понятно о чём говорят. И есть причина почему так. Как есть причина почему врачей называют докторами.

Comment: @Eagle Слово _филология_ переводится как любить + слово. Если вам понятно, что такое _философия_ (любить + мудрость), то, вестимо, и _филология_ должна быть равнопонятна. (Уверен, однако, что это не так.) Не каждое слово имеет точное значение. Вернее даже -- почти любое слово не имеет точного значения. И люди все же общаются и часто понимают друг друга. В этом одно из "чудес" языка, в этом же его многогранность -- когда "точного" значения слово не имеет, на помощь приходят прагматика, дискурс, экстралингвистические факторы... Но это уже совсем другой разговор.

Answer (score 0):

Так вопрос в чём? В определении филологии или в том, в чём разница?
Отвечу про разницу. Культурология намного шире. Это комплексный взгляд на культуру, включающий и архитектуру, и антропологию, и религоведение, и социологию. Не пытайтесь прочертить чёткие границы между науками. Наука — условное явление, описывающее единый мир. Всегда найдётся вопрос, в котором одна наука будет пересекаться с другой.
Филология — это более узкий предмет. Её задача в том, чтобы изучить, что стояло за текстами, кто их писал, для чего и в какой культурной среде.

Comment: Мой вопрос больше в определении филологии. Из тех определений, что я привёл получатся, что цель филологии не в том, чтоб изучить, как вы сказали *«что стояло за текстами, кто их писал, для чего и в какой культурной среде»*, а в том, чтоб изучать *культуру народа и историю и сущность духовной культуры общества*, и это не понятно. И ещё в определении сказано  *«изучающих письменные тексты»* и вы пишите: *«что стояло за текстами, кто их писал, для чего и в какой культурной среде»*. А что насчёт устой речи? Ней филология, получается, не занимается? И, получается, что она изучает только прошлое?

Comment: Не отрезайте часть от определения. Не "изучать культуру", а изучать "культуру, выраженную в литературе" и только в ней, но не за её пределами. Предмет исследования — культура, объект — литература. Филология — это именно исследование текстов. Разумеется, она изучает прошлое. Настоящее изучают лингвисты, а будущее прорицатели.

Comment: "Настоящее изучают лингвисты." Таким образом, лингвистика — это не часть филологии, а просто её инструмент? Я не отрезаю часть, просто выделяю цель. Можно изучать творчество Пушкина, а можно через его творчество изучать культуру народа. Но тогда, наша цель не литературная, а культурологическая. И тогда литературоведенье, это тоже не часть филологии, а только ей инструмент. Математика используется в физике для расчётов, но она не часть физики, а только инструмент. Значит филология — это не совокупность языкознания с литературоведением, а наука, которая изучает культуру с помощью этих дисциплин?

Comment: Ещё раз говорю: не проводите чётких границ. Это невозможно. Всё — часть всего, и во всём есть элементы другого. Без культуры вы не поймёте язык, без языка — культуру. Дробление на дисциплины условно, особенно, когда дело касается речи. Первично сознание, оно выражается в образах, образы в вербальной и невербальной речи, а она уже должна быть передана в письменной форме. И всё единый процесс выражения мысли. У вас никогда не получится герметично изучать, например, только синтаксис, потому что очень быстро попадётся пример, живущий по законам устной речи, отсылающий к культурному контексту.