# Почему в Интернете так распространено неправильное написание наречия "вряд ли" - "врятли"? Когда такое неправильное написание возникло?

Tags: орфография, наречия

Часто в Интернете можно встретить неправильное написание "вряд ли" - "врятли", особенно в соцсетях.

Comment: Никто не фиксирует, когда появляются неправильные написания! Хватит уже об этом спрашивать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**А вот это хороший вопрос,** зачем вы автора ругаете? И ответ очень простой.

Почему пишут неправильно? Как слышат, так и пишут (то есть используют з**вуковое, а не смысловое** письмо).

Чтобы понять, как писать правильно, надо к слову отнестись внимательно, о его происхождении задуматься. Оно обозначает **сомнение и неуверенность**, а почему?
Правильно то, что **"вписывается в ряд"**, то есть в систему вашего миропонимания. А частица ЛИ как раз говорит об обратном.

Падежная форма "в ряд" перешла в наречие и пишется слитно (вряд ли).

Comment: Ругаю второй вопрос, а не первый.

Comment: Прикол. Много раз говорил вам, что здесь не форум. Увидел такого пользователя: https://i.imgur.com/T3g2woR.png Было очень смешно. Он, видимо, уже устал об этом говорить и решил действовать другим путём.

Comment: No, this is a forum! In other words, a discussion site on the questions asked.

Comment: Нет, форумы созданы для общения, а этот сайт для создания базы данных с помощью вопросов и  ответов. А обычное общение здесь запрещено, всё должно касаться вопросов и ответов.

Comment: Вот официальное обсуждение по этому поводу: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92107

Comment: Но самое главное отличие во внешнем виде и строении: у форумов отличимый внешний вид, есть разделы, подразделы и лс. Если вы побываете на настоящем форуме, то всё поймёте и уже не будете называть любую площадку, где можно писать сообщения, форумом.

Comment: Ещё темы на формах часто начинаются не вопросом. Здесь же это запрещено. Форумы обязаны иметь разделы (основа основ). Без разделов не форум!

Comment: @oleedd, почему тогда наш сайт называется Форум лингвистов и филологов? Форум русского языка?

Comment: @Серж Где это написано? Не видел такого.

Comment: @oleedd, наш сайт, сколько помнится, всегда так назывался. Вот даже ссылка на вопрос о форуме. https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/18855/%d0%a4%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8-%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b3%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0

Comment: @Серж Нет, называется "сайт «Русский язык»" (посмотрите в поиск). Вот позиция создателей: https://i.imgur.com/x63dV51.png

Comment: Видимо, сейчас уже изменилось. Раньше так назывался. Даже когда в поисковике пишу название нашего сайта, пишу: Русский язык: форум. Или форум русского языка.

Comment: @Серж "Форум" — это о сайтостроении (тип сайтов), общение второстепенно. Программисты это хорошо понимают.